# Can I place a $interval call in a service?

Tags: angularjs

I have coded this:

```
 $interval(us.isAuthenticated(), 5 * 1000);
```

The auth service has the us service injected.

The code calls the isAuthenticated just one time and then does not call it any more. Is there a way to get around this or can I just not use the $interval this way?  How about if I put the call to $interval in the controller? I did already try in a function that is called with app.run but that didn't work more than once either

Comment: About the "isAuthenticated", if what you want to do is poll the server to check if the user has a session valid, why not placing an interceptor and when you get 401 or similar error you just redirect to the login page (login expired?). If you just want to check when the session is about to expire you could create a "Heading Controller" like and perform that polling there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
var v = us.isAuthenticated();
$interval(v, 5 * 1000);
```

So, assuming `us.isAuthenticated()` returns a boolean value, you're passing this boolean value to `$interval`. That's not what `$interval` expects. It expects a function to call repeatedly. So the code should be

```
$interval(us.isAuthenticated, 5 * 1000);
```

or

```
$interval(function() {
              us.isAuthenticated();
          }, 5 * 1000);
```

or

```
var functionToRepeat = function() {
    us.isAuthenticated();
};
$interval(functionToRepeat, 5 * 1000);
```

So, in short, you must pass it a function, instead of passing it the value returned by the function.

Comment: @OP here is https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval see that first argument of $interval is a function not boolean.
And JB Bingo :)

Answer (score 1):

You should call interval function from function call or you could pass reference, In addition to @JB Nizet answer you should also consider below pattern to call [**`$interval`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval), like below `invokeApply` is one of the parameter by using which you could turn off the dirty checking of that parameter.

**Code**

```
$interval(function() {
        us.isAuthenticated();
    },
    5 * 1000, //delay,
    100, //[count] it accepts number, 
    true, //[invokeApply]
    { param: 1} //any [Pass]
);
```